# how to know electrum wallet is synchronised?

Tags: bitcoind, client, electrum

I installed [electrum](https://electrum.org/#download) wallet 3.1.1 on my amazon linux server today. electrum daemon is running.

> [ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx electrumwallet]$ electrum is_synchronized
>   true
>   [ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx electrumwallet]$ electrum daemon status
>   {
>       "auto_connect": true,
>       "blockchain_height": 514484,
>       "connected": true,
>       "fee_per_kb": 3858,
>       "path": "/home/ec2-user/.electrum",
>       "server": "electrum-server.ninja",
>       "server_height": 514484,
>       "spv_nodes": 10,
>       "version": "3.1.1",
>       "wallets": {
>           "/home/ec2-user/.electrum/wallets/default_wallet": true
>       }
>   }

As far as I understand sending bitcoins to addresses of unsynchronized blockchain cannot be seen. How to know if the electrum wallet is fully synchronized and i can send bitcoins to electrum wallet addresses generated.?

Can someone explain fields of `electrum daemon status` result? Thanks in advance.